# Can I upload unpublished research in github?

Tags: research-process

I am a PhD student working on Catalysis. During this lockdown, I took some data science courses and did my own data science project in form of a meta-analysis from catalysis papers.

However, right now it is not possible for me to submit this work to a research journal as I want to conduct some additional studies on it.

Still, I want to show my data science skills in my resume and mentioning this project can be great. But without having a research publication right now, the project can't be visible online.

Thus, is it a good idea to upload the project on github now, so that interested people (maybe future recruiters) can look at the project before it is published in a good research journal?

Will it affect the future submission if I decide to submit the work to a peer reviewed journal later?

Comment: If you are asking about recruiters, this question is potentially out of scope because it's about industry jobs. But no - uploading your work to github will never affect future journal publications

Comment: One possible solution is to write a preprint describing nicely what you're uploading to github, and post it to something like arXiv. Later, when you're ready, publish it in a journal with the additional work that you plan. Pro: you clearly published it. Con: some journals would not want something that's already been posted, as you're probably aware.

Comment: @Taw Thanks for  your suggestion, but I couldn't get what you meant by the question is out of scope. Do you  mean that the  industrial recruiters won't care if the project is in github or is published in peer reviewed journals?

Comment: It's out of scope for this site because this is specifically for questions about academia.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, but keep in mind that everybody can see it. So people could use it:

- If they are not honest, they could try to publish the work itself under their own name. It's unlikely but possible. You could certainly prove the plagiarism but it would be quite unpleasant.
- If they are honest, they could use it to obtain some other results that they can legitimately publish under their own name. They would cite your github repository, but that's not as valuable for you as citing your paper.

The usual solution is to publish a preprint, i.e. a non peer reviewed paper which unambiguously shows that you are the author of this work and can be cited in case somebody does some other work based on yours. You can put a link to the preprint on your github repository, so that people know what to cite if they use it. Once you publish the work in a peer-reviewed journal or conference, you can update the link so that people cite the official paper.

Comment: Thank you  Erwan, your answer was quite helpful. I just wondered, will there be any copyright problem as I will have to upload almost similar figures in github repository and future publication? I guess there shouldn't be such a problem as github is open-source, but is there any chance?

Comment: @Keshri I'm not very knowledgeable about the legal details, but in general there shouldn't be any problem because nowadays all the journals allow preprints and associated github repositories are encouraged for reproducibility purposes. The fact that github is open-source is irrelevant though, the main issue would be whether the copyright can be transferred to the journal, which is a requirement most of the time. There are [some related questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=preprint+copyright) on the site in case you're interested.

Comment: Thank you  Erwan. It helped a lot !